# Baksmali error for android odex file

Tags: java, android, smali

I downloaded core.odex and framework.odex from my Samsung Galaxy Player, in order to make some changes for the hidden apis, following this webpage: https://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-2-hacking-around/

Also, I got baksmali and smali from here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1650243

Now, when I run the command: **java -jar baksmali-1.3.3.jar -c :core.odex -x framework.odex**, the following error appears:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
org.jf.dexlib.Util.ExceptionWithContext: regCount does not match the number of arguments of the method
    at org.jf.dexlib.Util.ExceptionWithContext.withContext(ExceptionWithContext.java:54)
    at org.jf.dexlib.Code.InstructionIterator.IterateInstructions(InstructionIterator.java:92)
    at org.jf.dexlib.CodeItem.readItem(CodeItem.java:154)
    at org.jf.dexlib.Item.readFrom(Item.java:76)
    at org.jf.dexlib.OffsettedSection.readItems(OffsettedSection.java:48)
    at org.jf.dexlib.Section.readFrom(Section.java:143)
    at org.jf.dexlib.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:431)
    at org.jf.baksmali.main.main(main.java:265)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: regCount does not match the number of arguments of the method
    at org.jf.dexlib.Code.Format.Instruction3rc.checkItem(Instruction3rc.java:129)
    at org.jf.dexlib.Code.Format.Instruction3rc.<init>(Instruction3rc.java:79)
    at org.jf.dexlib.Code.Format.Instruction3rc.<init>(Instruction3rc.java:44)
    at org.jf.dexlib.Code.Format.Instruction3rc$Factory.makeInstruction(Instruction3rc.java:145)
    at org.jf.dexlib.Code.InstructionIterator.IterateInstructions(InstructionIterator.java:84)
... 6 more
Error occured at code address 0
code_item @0x159a90
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Appreciate in advance any help you can provide.

Comment: Something like this is probably better reported at https://code.google.com/p/smali/issues/list. And on a (hopefully) more helpful note, try it with the current version of baksmali. 1.3.3 is old and unsupported :)

Comment: @JesusFreke: Thanks for the comment. Before posting the question in the link you mentioned I would like to try again with a new version of baksmali, where can I download a newer version?, if you can recommend a website I would appreciate it. And also, is the command I am using correct?

Comment: http://smali.googlecode.com. Take a look at https://code.google.com/p/smali/wiki/DeodexInstructions for instructions on how to deodex.